# Connecting to Cassandra Cluster from Springboot application throws "AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point" Exception

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, nosql, datastax-java-driver

Springboot application is failing to start up because it is failing to connect to the Cassandra contact points. Though the same configuration is working with localhost Cassandra setup but not with the actual Cassandra cluster. Configuration class is given below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "xyz.abc" })
public class CassandraConfiguration extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Value("${cassandra.contactpoints}")
    private String contactPoints;

    @Value("${cassandra.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${cassandra.keyspace}")
    private String keySpace;

    @Value("${cassandra.schema-action}")
    private String schemaAction;
    
    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return keySpace;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getContactPoints() {
        return contactPoints;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getPort() {
        return port;
    }
    

    @Override
    public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return SchemaAction.valueOf(schemaAction);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception message you posted indicates that your application is not able to reach any of the nodes in your cluster.

You haven't provided details of your environment or how you've configured your cluster but the exception mostly relates to networking. You need to make sure that there is network connectivity between your app instances and all the [local] nodes of the Cassandra cluster you're connecting to. Check that there is no firewall blocking access to the CQL client port (default is `9042`) on the nodes.

Also check that the Cassandra nodes are configured to listen for client connections on a publicly-reachable interface -- `rpc_address` in `cassandra.yaml` should not be set to a private address.

Use Linux utilities such as `nc`, `telnet`, `netstat` and `lsof` to assist with your troubleshooting. Cheers!